# Transforming a numpy matrix dataset

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 2D matrix in python with 8 columns.
Those 8 column hold records of two different entities, say A, and B, each having 4 columns. My example data looks like:

```
╔══════╦═════════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ A_ID ║ arrtibA ║ B_ID ║ attribB ║
╠══════╬═════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║ val     ║    1 ║ val     ║
║    1 ║ val     ║    1 ║ val     ║
║    1 ║ val     ║    2 ║ val     ║
║    1 ║ val     ║    2 ║ val     ║
║    2 ║ val     ║    3 ║ val     ║
║    2 ║ val     ║    3 ║ val     ║
║    2 ║ val     ║    4 ║ val     ║
║    3 ║ val     ║    5 ║ val     ║
║    3 ║ val     ║    5 ║ val     ║
╚══════╩═════════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

And I want this to be transformed into this form:

```
╔══════╦═════════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ A_ID ║ arrtibA ║ B_ID ║ attribB ║
╠══════╬═════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║ val     ║    1 ║ val     ║
║    1 ║ val     ║    1 ║ val     ║
║    2 ║ val     ║    2 ║ val     ║
║    2 ║ val     ║    2 ║ val     ║
║    3 ║ val     ║    3 ║ val     ║
╚══════╩═════════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

In simpler words, aligning the attributes of entity A, and entity B on the basis of their respective IDs. The rows which do not find a match can be discarded. I've about 28,000+ rows, where A_ID ranges from 17 to 230, and B_ID ranges from 17 to 305. But once alignment is done, the rows where IDs for both entities are below 231 are aligned in front of each other, and rest from 231 to 305 of entity B get discarded.

Comment: You are mixing terminology. `pandas` has Dataframes.  Numpy only has arrays.  I'd suggest a MCV example

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
data = np.delete(data, np.where(data[:,0]!=data[:,2])[0], 0)
```

Comment: well, that, in the case ob given example, will only keep the top 2 rows, and delete the rest. I need to align them

Comment: Alright I may not have fully understood your question, what do you mean by 'aligning the attributes of entity A, and entity B on the basis of their respective IDs' ? In your example you have 4 rows with A_ID == 1 and 2 rows with B_ID == 1, so, you want to keep only the first 2 rows with A_ID == 1, remove the 2 entries in the 1st and 2d columns e.g. cells (3,4) and (4,4) (so cols 1 and 2 'slide up') and repeat on ID == 2, 3, 4... ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Only two entries of A_ID == 1 will be removed, and the lower values with A_ID == 2 will "slide up", in front of the entries where B_ID == 2, and so on with 3, 4, 5...

Comment: So far, I've divided the dataset into separate columns for the rows of entity A, and B. So, according to the example, if I have 4 columns, now, I have 2 matrices of 2 columns each.